# Diffrence between async/await and ContinueWith

Tags: vb.net

Consider this example:

```
 Private Async Function ComputeText() As Task(Of String)
        Dim result As String = Await Task.Run(Function()
                                                  'do whatever

                                                  Return "Done"

                                              End Function)

        Return result
    End Function
```

Now could anyone tell me whether there is diffrence between those two button event handlers? From my perspective this is the same but 'better approach' is to use the 1st one, am i right?

```
'1st: 
      Private Async Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
             LabelCounter.Text = "Running"

            Dim value As string = Await ComputeText()
            LabelCounter.Text = value

        End Sub

    '2nd:
        Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
             LabelCounter.Text = "Running"

            Dim task = ComputeText().ContinueWith(
                Sub(x)
                    LabelCounter.Invoke(
                        Sub()
                            LabelCounter.Text = x.Result
                        End Sub)
                End Sub)
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Await` does use `ContinueWith` under the hood. However, [`ContinueWith` is a dangerous API](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) and should not be used directly. As I describe in my post on [task continuations](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html):

- `ContinueWith` has an unfortunate choice of default sceduler; it uses `TaskScheduler.Current` rather than `TaskScheduler.Default`.
- `ContinueWith` does not understand asynchronous delegates, so it will return an extra task wrapper that you have to unwrap (by calling `Unwrap`).
- `ContinueWith` does not have appropriate default option arguments for asynchronous code (e.g., `TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach` and `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`).

For these reasons, you should use `Await` instead of `ContinueWith` for asynchronous code.

Also, it's shorter and prettier. :)

Comment: of course i will use await. So was i right at main topic correct?

Comment: @JimmyJimm: They're not quite the same, but they will both update `Text` on the UI thread.